# Rails: rescue_from and rethrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I want to track my user's exception with mixpanel so I added this code in my application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    if Rails.env.production?
          tracker.track(session[:mixpanel_unauth_id], 'Exception', {:exception => exception.to_s})
          rescue_action_without_handler(exception)
    end
  end
```

I just want to intercept the error for mixpanel than the error must be re thrown normally.

In production a have a method not found error on rescue_action_without_handler

In development I have a blank white page when an error happen.

How to solve this problem?
I use Rails 3.2